# Adding multiple nodes at once in xml

Tags: c#, xml, nullreferenceexception

My xml is this:

```
<Settings>
    <Ss></Ss>
    <Properties>
        <Property>
            <Name>x</Name>
            <Description>xx</Description>
        </Property>
            <Property>
            <Name>y</Name>
            <Description>yyyyy</Description>
            </Property>
    </Properties>
</Settings>
```

I want to add as a son of Properties an XElement. This is my code:

```
XDocument xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\FileXml.xml");
xmlDoc1.Element("Properties").Add(new XElement(addManyNodes));
```

But it doesn't work. It throws null reference exception. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the root of the XDocument is `<Settings>` and the root itself is not `<Properties>` you get a `null` value from `Element("Properties")`.

You need to drill down using [`XDocument.Root`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) or a chain of calls to `Element` or `Descendants`. Here are a few options:

```
// simplest
xmlDoc1.Root.Element("Properties").Add(new XElement(addManyNodes));

// using a chain of Element calls
xmlDoc1.Element("Settings").Element("Properties").Add(...);
```

Another way to look at it:

```
<!-- xmlDoc1 -->
<Settings> <!-- .Root or .Element("Settings") -->
    <Ss></Ss> <!-- .Root.Element("Ss") or .Element("Settings").Element("Ss") -->
    <Properties> <!-- .Root.Element("Properties") -->
        <Property> <!-- .Root.Element("Properties").Element("Property") -->
```

One final note, if `addManyNodes` is already an array:

```
xmlDoc1.Root.Element("Properties").Add(addManyNodes);
```

Once you've made your changes, [you should save it to the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx):

```
xmlDoc1.Save(...);
```

Comment: I've gone ahead and added some additional info about adding multiple nodes and saving the document when you're through making changes.